# Select que mostre todas tabelas que possuem campos com tipo de dados especifico

Tags: mysql

Tenho um banco de dados que preciso alterar todas as colunas que estão em FLOAT E DOUBLE para DECIMAL, são mais ou menos 150 tabelas e perco muito tempo olhando uma a uma, existe algum comando que me mostre isso?

Banco de Dados MY SQL, uso workbench 6.3

Obrigado.

Comment: Existi, você vai precisar fazer uma busca por suas tabelas no banco com o nome das tabelas você terá que fazer um curso para percorrer todas as tabelas uma a uma e verificar se existe a coluna que você quer. [Veja essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183553/show-all-tables-inside-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer de uma forma simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maravilha, achei o que precisava :D

Segue o código:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nome_do_meu_banco_de_dados'
        AND (DATA_TYPE = 'FLOAT'
        OR DATA_TYPE = 'DOUBLE')
```

Eu encontrei neste link: http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/tabelas-e-colunas-no-mysql.html

Obrigado.